# Can't provoke MongoError - bad auth

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Just to be clear, I **want** to get `MongoError bad auth Authentication failed` from MongoDB Atlas.
This is about wrong DB password and I'm trying to catch that error and act accordingly.

this is my connection method:

```
mongoose
  .connect(CRED, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to database');
  });
```

---

and here I'm catching **unhandledRejection** error that supposed to catch wrong auth:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

If I put correct password, everything works fine and I'm connected to database.
But if I put wrong password, after 30 sec of waiting I get:

```
MongooseTimeoutError Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

...and this shouldn't suppose to work like that.
I should get **MongoError (bad auth)** immediately, on first attempt when app is connecting to MongoDB
...or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8180) for Mongoose <=5.7.1 with `useUnifiedTopology: true` option.

### Update your Mongoose to 5.9.2 to fix the issue.

With new version, Mongoose fails corectly:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: Authentication failed.
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (D:\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:808:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\myapp\app.js:46:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  message: 'Authentication failed.',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Also, add `.catch` clause to your code

```
mongoose
  .connect(CRED, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
     console.log('connected to database');
  })
  .catch(error => {
     //MongooseServerSelectionError MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: Authentication failed
     console.log("Error", error)
  });
```

Comment: hi, thx for answer. I've updated to 5.9.2 from 5.8.11 and now I'm getting **MongooseServerSelectionError bad auth Authentication failed** which is progress and I hope correct error. I didn't want to use `.catch()` on connect, but instead catching unhandled errors globally in app. Anyway, same error was thrown when I tested it (catch rejected promise), server timeout.